# SpringBoot: how to test if the service is up and running using rest-assured

Tags: spring-boot, rest-assured

In my spring boot application how can I test if the service is up and running using rest assured. the main() is defined like this -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test should look like this

```
public class ApplicationTest {

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:8080";
    }

    @Test
    public void testStatus() {
        given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).get("/greeting").prettyPeek().then().statusCode(200);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMessage() {
        given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).get("/greeting").then()
            .body("content", is("Hello, World!"));
    }

}
```

Include dependency below in your build tool:

Gradle:

```
testCompile('com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured:2.4.1')
```

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```